# Downloading old QGIS version

Tags: qgis, download

I am using QGIS 2.18 on my old laptop, but I just got a new laptop and don't have time at the moment to learn QGIS 3.  Googled downloading 2.18 but the responses seemed to require me to download some other software before downloading 2.18, which I am suspicious of.

Eventually I will dive in to 3, but for right now what is a safe and reliable way for me to download 2.18 on my new laptop?

Comment: Where did you download from? Try this side, it's the official download linked to from the QGIS main website: https://download.osgeo.org/qgis/ - it's the OSGeo4W Network Installer. I'm not sure if there is another possibility to get older versions. I would try to get a current version to see if your workflow is so diferent there that you need substantial training.

Comment: How about these https://qgis.org/downloads/

Comment: I think it's harder to learn how to install an old version instead of the subtle differences between qgis 2 and 3; pretty much is the change from shp to gpkg as standard and using python 3, which most things written in py 2 will work by adding parentheses to the print lines

Answer (score 6):

You can download them as usual here: https://qgis.org/downloads/ and here for Mac: https://qgis.org/downloads/macOS/

You can find all links on qgis.org within downloads / all releases: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

But also note, that if you are used to QGIS 2, you will have no problems with QGIS 3.