download specific QGIS Version on Windows
I want to download QGIS Version 3.36.1. How can I download it? On the QGIS website, we can't choose which version we want—only the LTR and the newest build are available. See:


You may have a look at https://download.qgis.org/downloads/

Answered here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382949/downloading-old-qgis-version.

Thank you @IliasMachairas !
